# How to create/manipulate databases and tables from custom UI panel using Java(Fx)?

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, java-8

I've been working on Java(FX) project in which all the CRUD operations can be performed, for operating XAMPP server (PHPMyAdmin panel), I've made a Dash Board Pane from which user can set Custom Settings of localhost i.e Local Host Username and password. By default, the username is 'root' and password is '' (null), But what if the user has changed the localhost settings and they want to access it from desktop Application with custom username and password.
And
Users can also be able to search and select a particular database for performing CRUD operations.
I need SQL queries for accessing localhost Databases.

[Image will Describe Full Concept of Question from Front-End (GUI)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BrWC.jpg)

**Additionally**: How can we check how many database engines are currently installed or running in clients system?

Comment: _At the risk of stating the painfully obvious_ Userid and Password go into your database connection. So I would expect you can work out what to do with the Userid and Password you collect from the login dialog of your app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to login with your username and password to the mysql server(in your case at localhost mysql server) then you can use the

```
show databases;
```

command to get a list of all databases

Comment: P.S the show databases; is like a simple query. check an example here at  sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/81

Comment: is 'show databases' statement works on all the sql platforms like Oracle 10g, phpmyadmin and MySql. If user have all three of them installed in system with different ports ?

Comment: P.S if the answer is helpful mark it as correct and upvote it.